# How to set Pinescript stop loss

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have no idea how to set the stop loss on my pinescript.

Expected result 1: If initial capital is $1000, if my trade is losing 10% from my capital. It will immediately cut lost.

Expected result 2: If my trade is losing $100 dollars. it will immediately cut lost.

```
//@version=5
strategy("Bollinger Bands Strategy", overlay=true)

length = input.int(20, "Length", minval=1)
src = input(close, title="Source")
mult = input.float(2.0, "StdDev", minval=0.001, maxval=50)
basis = ta.sma(src, length)
dev = mult * ta.stdev(src, length)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev

// Buy condition
buyCondition = ta.crossover(close, lower)
// Sell condition
sellCondition = ta.crossunder(close, upper)

strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, when=buyCondition)
strategy.close("Buy", when=sellCondition)

// Plotting
plot(basis, "Basis", color=color.orange)
p1 = plot(upper, "Upper", color=color.blue)
p2 = plot(lower, "Lower", color=color.blue)
fill(p1, p2, title="Background", color=color.new(color.blue, 90))
```

[image]

I need help on that.